# Retornar um CURSOR de uma procedure SqlServer com sql dinamico (sp_executesql)

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

No oracle eu posso fazer da seguinte forma :

```
OPEN MY_CURSOR FOR 'SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE'
```

Como obter esse resultado no SqlSever? Quero retornar um cursor montando um sql dinâmico na procedure.
Atualmente estou usando assim:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MY_PROC(@PARAM INT)
AS
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jeterson, você vai estar combinando o pior dos dois mundos, um cursor e uma query dinamica, mas você deve saber a necessidade..

Olha esse exemplo:

```
declare @sSQL nvarchar(4000)
Declare @des_Name VarChar(200)

set @sSQL = 'Declare Teste_cursor CURSOR FOR Select name from sys.objects'

exec sp_executesql @sSQL

OPEN Teste_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM Teste_cursor
INTO @des_Name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
Print @des_Name


FETCH NEXT FROM Teste_cursor
INTO @des_Name

END
CLOSE Teste_cursor
DEALLOCATE Teste_cursor
```